# Retrieve XML parent and child attributes using Python and lxml

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to process an XML file using XPATH in Python / lxml.

I can pull out the values at a particular level of the tree using this code:

```
file_name = input('Enter the file name, including .xml extension: ') # User inputs file name
print('Parsing ' + file_name)

from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(file_name, parser)

r = tree.xpath('/dataimport/programmelist/programme')
print (len(r))

with open(file_name+'.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:        
   for r in tree.xpath('/dataimport/programmelist/programme'):
        progid = (r.get("id"))
        print (progid)
```

It returns a list of values as expected.  I also want to return the value of a 'child' (where it exists), but I can't work out how (I can only get it to work as a separate list, but I need to maintain the link between them).

Note: I will be writing the values out to a log file, but since I haven't been successful in getting everything out that I want, I haven't added the 'write out' code yet.

This is the structure of the XML:

```
<dataimport dtdversion="1.1">
   <programmelist>
      <programme id="eid-273168">
         <imageref idref="img-1844575"/>
```

How can I get Python to return the id + idref?

The previous examples I have worked with had namespaces, but this file doesn't.

Comment: You sample code is not consistent. Where do you use `f`? What is `tree`? Are you reading the file or writing in it?

Comment: Updated - Sorry, should have included it in the first place

Comment: I've added it in the body above, but please note that the results will eventually be written to a log file (hence the reference to 'with open(file_name'.log, 'w'...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `xpath()` method returns tree, you can use xpath again to get idref list you want:

```
for r in tree.xpath('/dataimport/programmelist/programme')
    progid = r.get("id")
    ref_list = r.xpath('imageref/@idref')
    print progid, ref_lis
```

Comment: That works, thanks!  How can I get rid of the square brackets and inverted commas? I tried to use a str() and then cut it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Nick: ref_list is a normal python list, so python string method `join()` would be enough: `print "%s: %s" % (progid, " ".join(ref_list))`